# Number of lattice points inside a right-angled triangle with one of the points having a rational coordinate

Tags: geometry

I just found out about Pick's theorem and was having trouble with this variation of it.

Consider a right-angled triangle with vertices at $(0,0)$, $(a,0)$ and $ (a,b)$; where $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and  $b = \frac{p}{q}$. $p$ and $q$ can be assumed to be coprime. We need to find the number of lattice points inside this triangle.

I think we can do this by rescaling our grid by multiplying each point by $q$ but I am unable to proceed using this approach.

Any pointers on how can we solve this problem? Does any closed from solution exists for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just try to give answer to what I think your question is.

you want number of lattice points (integer grid) inside your triangle, I will count ones on triangle vertices. Your triangle also has very nice coordinates so it makes this quite simple. Solution is

$$\sum_{n=0}^{a} (\lfloor {\frac{b}{a}n} \rfloor +1)$$

here is why. $y=\frac{b}{a}x$ is equation of line that goes through $(0,0)$ and $(a,b)$ we need to sum number of lattice points below this line and above $y=0$ which is line that goes through $(0,0)$ and $(a,0)$. We get this by summing for all integer $x$ between $0$ and $a$ floor of $\frac{b}{a}x$ and we add 1 because we also count $(x,0)$